# Wait for data to be input then run sub.

Tags: vba, excel

I need a very simple system that saves a bar code number to a sheet every time it is scanned. It works great but I have to click a cmd button in between each scan or hit enter. Is there any was I could use the execute after the text box changes? But if I use the 
    Private Sub txtCode_Change() 
As a title then it only takes the first number of the code and uses that instead of waiting the .25 seconds for the rest of the bar code to be imputed. Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can configure your bar-code scanner to send an <kbd>Enter</kbd> or a <kbd>Tab</kbd> key after the scanned bar-code.

- If your scanner sends a <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, you can use the `TextBox_AfterUpdate` event:

  ```
  Private Sub txtCode_AfterUpdate()
      'Do something.
  End Sub
  ```
- If your scanner sends an <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, you can use the `TextBox_KeyDown` event:

  ```
  Private Sub txtCode_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, _
                              ByVal Shift As Integer)
      If KeyCode = vbKeyReturn Then
          'Do something.
      End If
  End Sub
  ```
- If your bar-code is a fixed-length string, you can still use the `TextBox_Change` event like the following:

  ```
  Private Const BARCODE_LENGTH As Integer = 12

  Private Sub txtCode_Change()
      If Len(txtCode.Text) = BARCODE_LENGTH Then
          'Do something
      End If
  End Sub
  ```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! The keydown works perfectly! I really appreciate the help!